# How do you spawn Iron Golems in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Playing in creative mode, my village has only one Iron Golem. I think it was attracted to my golem costume skin. How do I spawn more without an actual spawner?

Comment: Is it not the same as PC minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

You take 4 iron blocks and stack two on top and one on each side of the top block.  Then put a pumpkin or jack o' lantern on to then you get an iron golem.

Image:

[image]

Comment: So is it the same as in normal minecraft?